# как в ajax вести всю информацию с .json методом fetch

Tags: javascript

оно выводит [object Object],[object Object] а нужно всю ее информацию

этого json

```
[
    {
        "Name": "vasya",
        "lastName": "vasev",

    },
    {
        "Name": "micha",
        "lastName": "misckin",

    },

]
```

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.load');

var text = document.querySelector('.text');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e){

e.preventDefault();

  fetch('01.json')
  .then(function(data){
   
    return data.json();

  })
  .then(function(data){
    let {}= data;
    text.innerHTML += data;
console.log(data);


  })
})
```

```html
<button class="load">загрузить данные</button>
<p class="text"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(data);
```

Comment: спасибо, если не сложно как еще и добавить в .json

Comment: @Starbax Не понял вопроса.